# Maclaurin Series differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The Maclaurin series of $f(x)$ is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1}x^{2n-1} $$

Find the fifth derivative of $ f(x) $ at $ x = 0$.

**A.** 3!

**B.** 4!

**C.** 5!

**D.** 6!

**E.** 7!

---

The correct answer should be **B**, but I'm stumped on this one. Can someone lend me a hand? The farthest I got was noticing that the inner equation is obviously the integral of $ x^{2n} $, but I don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: what's the 3rd term x 120???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient on the $n$'th term of a taylor series around $a$ is given by 
$$
\frac{f^{k}(a)}{k!}=a_k
$$
Setting $a=0$ since it is a maclaurin series, $k=2n-1=5$, we have
$$
\frac{f^{5}(0)}{5!}=a_5=\frac{1}{5}\implies f^{5}(0)=\frac{5!}{5}=4!
$$

Comment: I don't understand your work completely... How did you get that the 5th term "a5" = 1/5? And why does the 5th derivative equal 5!/5?

Comment: $a_5$ is the coefficient on the $x^5$ term. Setting $2n-1=5$ to figure out what $n$ is for the $x^5$ term does the trick. your second question follows from the first formula for the coefficients o fa power series.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking stupid questions here... But once you have n = 3, what do you do with that information?

Comment: Plug it into the first expression as I did in the above.

Comment: I'm definitely gunna take the L on this exam

Comment: @Someguy why? Take the first equation as a definition; the rest really is algebra

Answer (score 1):

The $k$th derivative of a Maclaurin series is $k!$ times the coefficient of $x^k$ (i.e. for $ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, $f^{(k)}(0) = k!a_k$). Here, $k=5$, and the power of $x$, is $2n-1$. $2n-1=5$ when $n=3$. The coefficient of $x^5 = x^{2 \times 3-1}$ is then $1/(2 \times 3-1)=1/5$, so the answer is
$$ 5! \times \frac{1}{5} = 4!. $$